# Suitable regression method Linear, mixed or non linear

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, correlation, mixed-model

I have the below data related to a clinical study. I would like to understand if there is a correlation in prescribing the prescription per Genral practioner. In the data there are 3 GP's handling 14 patients GP 1 handled 5 patients, GP 2 handled 4 patients and GP 3. I want to know if the patients have strong or weak correlation in terms of having similar number of prescriptions prescribed by their GP. To understand the correlation by group what is the suitable method I can apply? Thank you for your help.

```
GP_Id Pat_Id    Total_prescribed_prescriptions
1   a   1
1   b   2
1   c   4
1   d   1
1   e   2
2   f   7
2   g   2
2   h   1
2   i   7
3   j   8
3   k   9
3   l   4
3   m   6
3   n   4
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me - are you interested in knowing if the GPs differ in the number of prescriptions they make on average ?

Comment: Hi Robert, For example, on average if GP has prescribed same number of prescriptions or not to the patients visited him. Is what I wanted to understand statistically.

Answer (score 1):

The dataset is quite small so anything we find here should be treated cautiously.

The first thing I would do here is to plot the data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
GP <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
presc <- c(1,2,4,1,2,7,2,1,7,8,9,4,6,4)
dt <- data.frame(GP = as.factor(GP), presc)
ggplot(dt, aes(y = presc, x = GP, color = GP)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

From this we can see there is clear evidence that GP3 issues more prescriptions that GP1. There is also some evidence that GP2 issues more prescriptions that GP1, and a little less evidence that GP3 issues more prescriptions than GP2

We could also fit a regression model. Since the data are counts, this would be a generalised linear model with a poisson family distribution.

```r
> summary(glm(presc ~ GP, data = dt, family = poisson))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)   0.6931     0.3162   2.192  0.02839 * 
GP2           0.7538     0.3985   1.891  0.05857 . 
GP3           1.1314     0.3637   3.111  0.00186 **
```

This concurs with our visual findings: There is strong evidence that GP3 issues more prescriptions that GP1, and moderate evidence that GP2 issues more prescriptions that GP1.

Again, I would recommend using caution with these findings due to the small sample size.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you so much for the detailed explaination. Does this analysis also explain about the between group variance and the within group variance. Group of GP's considered as between group variance and patients treated by a GP considered as within group variance. Many thanks!!

Comment: With only 4 or 5 observations in each group I don't think it makes a lot of sense to think about between and within-group variance. Of course you can just compute the variances for each GP, and I'm sure you will see, as seems obvious from the boxplots, that there is a lot more variation for GP2 than GP3 which in turn is more variable than GP1.

Comment: Actually I have provided only sample data due to the confidentiality of the data but actual data is about 8000 records. Your recommendation of implementing GLM with Poisson family distribution suits the data very well to generate the between and within-group variance. Using Intracluster correlation formula (variance s_b^2 between the clustered group / variance s_b^2 between the clustered group + mean square error s_w^2 within group variance) can generate the coefficient to indicate similarity and relatedness of the prescriptions. Do you also think so with the data of 8000 patients and 350 GPs?

Comment: Hmm. That changes things a bit. I wish I had known that ! So if you run that poisson GLM with that dataset you are going to get 349 estimates, for all the GPs.  I'm not sure that that formula is in you last comment, and now I am not sure what your actual research question is. If you are looking for an ICC then perhaps a better approach is a generalised linear mixed model with random intercepts for GP.